# Problem to drop a table because of tr_MStran_droptable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have several databases with similar structures on several servers. I have a job who drop a table and recreate it in the night for every database. But I had a problem with only one database on one server :

> Invalid value given for parameter @procmapid. Specify a valid
>   parameter value.

I made some research and I have seen that the problem was because the trigger tr_MStran_droptable was enabled. So I disable it and now it works. But on my other database this trigger is enabled too and I can drop the table.

How it is possible? I can't find this trigger structure to study it in the database too. Did somebody know more about the trigger tr_MStran_droptable?

Trigger code :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [tr_MStran_droptable] ON DATABASE
FOR DROP_TABLE AS

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

DECLARE @EventData XML

SET @EventData = EventData()

IF object_id('dbo.sysarticles') IS NULL
    OR object_id('dbo.syspublications') IS NULL
    OR object_id('dbo.sysextendedarticlesview') IS NULL
    OR EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM @EventData.nodes('/EVENT_INSTANCE') AS R(event_instance)
        WHERE lower(event_instance.value('SchemaName[1]', 'sysname')) IN (
                N'sys'
                ,N'cdc'
                )
            OR lower(event_instance.value('ObjectName[1]', 'sysname')) IN (
                N'sysextendedarticlesview'
                ,N'sysarticles'
                ,N'syspublications'
                )
            OR event_instance.value('ObjectName[1]', 'sysname') LIKE N'#%'
        )
    RETURN

EXEC sys.sp_MStran_ddlrepl @EventData
    ,5
GO

DISABLE TRIGGER [tr_MStran_droptable] ON DATABASE
GO
```

Comment: check the "tr_MStran_droptable" Code, It's a user-defined trigger. Post the trigger code.

Comment: *"I made some research and I have seen that the problem was because the trigger tr_MStran_droptable was enabled"* - DDL or DML trigger? What kind of error occurs?

Comment: @XAMT I don't know where I can find the trigger code ?

Comment: @МаксимЗолотенко the error was I can't drop the table because of a trigger

Comment: 1. [CurrentDatabase] > Programmabilty > Database Triggers

Comment: 2. [CurrentServer] > Server Objects > Triggers

Comment: @XAMT It's added in the question

Comment: Oddly enough - a trivial search on that trigger name finds [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158394/having-issue-with-tr-mstran-droptable). And that is one reason why you should always identify the version, edition, and sp level of sql server you are using.

Comment: And [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4733/solving-table-drop-error-related-to-sql-server-replications-spmstranddlrepl/) which suggests corruption to the meta-data or an ad-hoc update to the meta-data. Perhaps the bigger concern is that you a job that completely recreates a table every day - which seems terribly inefficient.

Comment: @ManonFredout; Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Because of the trigger :

The trigger is to keep replication alive so :

Try running `sp_removedbreplication 'CurrentDatabase'` that will remove replication

or

Disable Trigger : `DISABLE TRIGGER [tr_MStran_droptable] ON DATABASE`